# What are the different colours of magic and what do they do?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii

In Find Mii, each hero's shirt colour refers to a different type of magic.

What are all the different colours? What does each colour of magic do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this forum thread](http://www.3dsbuzz.com/3ds-forum/nintendo-3ds-games-software-11/streetpass-quest-find-mii-magic-guide-2564/):

> - White: fills the area with a bright light. Its only use is on the second to last level, so save them if you can!
> - Red: attacks ghosts with flames. For the best effect, use against blue ghosts; don't use it against blood ghosts, since it doesn't affect them.
> - Orange: invigorates heroes. To put it simply, it makes your heroes have an extra attack if you use the sword (instead of attacking three times, you attack four times). It goes away if pink, black, or yellow magic is used after it.
> - Yellow: creates a sandstorm. It makes sword attacks less accurate, but it makes enemies rub their eyes to get sand out of them occasionally, making another chance to attack arise. If orange, black, or pink magic is used after it, the sandstorm goes away. If you're at the beginning of the quest, it's best to just save these for the ghost with the yellow shield (if you attack it with the yellow hero's sword, it breaks).
> - Chartreuse: puts the enemies to sleep. With this, the hero can keep attacking until the foe wakes up! This, coupled with pink magic, can tear right through even a blood ghost if you aren't unlucky and the foe wakes up soon after.
> - Dark green: strengthens the next hero. In other words, it makes a level 1 hero level 2, a level 2 hero level 4, and so on. This is very powerful if used with pink magic!
> - Cyan: freezes ghosts. Not really much to say other than that.
> - Blue: attacks enemies with a torrent of water. For best use, use it against blood ghosts.
> - Purple: poisons enemies. The poison does one damage to each enemy each turn, regardless of their defense or the level of the Mii/cat that casts it.
> - Pink: fills heroes with daring. It boosts the critical hit ratio from rare to nearly every turn (if not every turn). Critical hits triple the damage that the attacker would usually do, but only if the attack is with the sword. It goes away if orange, yellow, or black magic is used after it. This lowers the accuracy of the attacks, though.
> - Brown: summons a level 1-2 wandering hero (which will always be a bunny) of a random color. I recommend you don't use the magic unless a level 1 hero has it, since the bunnies are usually level 1.
> - Black: darkens the room. This lowers the accuracy of sword attacks, but makes another opening for an attack come up occasionally.